# Laravel валидация по regex

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, laravel, валидация

Делаю валидацию формы с ларавельным валидатором, ругается на `'vk_url' => 'regex:/^(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?vk\.com\/(\w|\d)+?\/?$/'`, а именно:

```
ErrorException in Validator.php line 1805:
preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found
```

выражение вроде стандартного вида, перепробовал уже много вариантов. В каком виде валидатор принимает регулярки, как нужно переделать это выражение?

Comment: Тут скорее всего надо передать этот параметр в виде массива. Кстати, здесь `(\w|\d)+?` = `\w+`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, спасибо, заменил на `\w+` и сработало

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Laravel есть определенные особенности работы с регулярками. Чаще всего возникают пробелемы  именно с оператором ИЛИ, так как символы `|` используются самим Laravel для передачи массива параметров.

Это описано в [документации](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-regex) (по-английски): "При использовании регулярных выражений может возникнуть необходимость указать правила в виде массива вмесио разделителей `|`, особенно если в самом регулярном выражении используется данный символ." (в моем вольном переводе).

В вашем конкретном случае можно просто избавится от этого оператора:

```
'vk_url' => 'regex:/^(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?vk\.com\/\w+\/?$/'
                                                      ^^^^
```

так как `\w` находит и цифры тоже.